# Scanning software invoked via buttons on scanner

Tags: scanning

I am trying to find some software that will integrate with the scanner properties events tab.

I don't quite know what to call it, so if someone knows a better search term than "scanner events" please let me know.

On Windows, if you go to `Devices and Printers`, right click on a scanner and go to `Scan Properties` you'll find an `Events` tab. Inside that tab you can choose actions that are associated with the buttons on the scanner.

Right now I can choose between HP's broken software, or Windows' image scanner (which won't do PDF.) I'm looking for a peice of software that can interface with that menu so I can choose something other than HP or Windows for scanning my documents.

I don't want this to be a "software recommendation" question so much as it is a "does this software exist, if so what might I search for to find it" question.

Comment: I am guessing any scanning capable software would fit the bill.  Have you tried any?  Here is an open source one: http://www.chronoscan.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Yes, I've tried VueScan, Scan2PDF, and a few others I found. None of them show up in this list of available programs :( Thanks, I'll go try ChronoScan now.

Comment: I'm not sure just any old program will do. My scanner for example doesn't even *have* an Events tab under Scan Properties! It's possible this feature is scanner-specific and only pre-approved apps work.